# How to handle gltf loading error in react-three-fiber?

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I think my question is pretty simple but I can't figure out a way to manage error handling with useLoader from react-three-fiber library.

I would like to render the Box when LoadGLTF tries to load the gltf file with a path that doesn't exist. I've already tried plenty of things but none of them seems to work...

Any help will be appreciated,

Thanks,

```
function Box(props) {
  // This reference will give us direct access to the mesh
  const mesh = useRef()
  return (
    <mesh
      {...props}
      ref={mesh}
    >
      <boxBufferGeometry args={[1, 1, 1]} />
      <meshStandardMaterial color='white'/>
    </mesh>
  )
}

function LoadGltf({url, ...props }) {
  const {nodes} = useLoader(GLTFLoader, url, onerror => {
    
  }); 
  
  const mesh = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    mesh.current.rotation.y = 3.14/180*315;  
  });
  useFrame(() => (mesh.current.rotation.y += 0.005)); 

  return (
    <mesh
    ref={mesh}
    name="Cover"
    geometry={nodes ? nodes.jambe.geometry : null}
    scale={[0.2,0.2,0.2]}
    material= {nodes ? nodes.jambe.material : null}
    >      
    </mesh>       
  )
}



function Product3D(props) {

  return (
    <div>
      <Canvas
        camera={{ position: [1, 0, 0] }}
        style={{  width:"75%",height:"500px", margin:"auto", marginTop:"30px", border : "solid #ffffff 1px", borderRadius:"10px" }} 
        >
          <pointLight position={[40, 40, 40]} />
          <ambientLight/>
          <CameraControls />
          <Suspense fallback={<Box position={[-1.2, 0, 0]} />}>  
            <LoadGltf url={props.url_gltf}/>
          </Suspense>
      </Canvas>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: errors in react are handled with error boundaries. the 3rd arg in useloader is onProgress